# Record Shop Financial Data with PYTHON

Tags: python

I'm really new to PYTHON and my only experience is some Codecademy Python exercises. I'm currently running a sweet/candy shop and wanted to be able to record my financial data using Python. Any ideas on how to do this in a relatively simple way?

Comment: This seems like quite a broad question. What specifically are you looking to use Python for. Can you describe it?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I was hoping to be able to record data such as revenue, profit, profit margin etc. for many different products. I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi. The options are database or file. If you want to store data in a file, learn OpenPyXl(for Excel spreadsheets), Python csv module for CSV or TSV. If you want to use a database, you can look at SQLAlchemy and basic SQL courses like Codecademy or TutorialsPoint.

Comment: Any reason why this has to be python, and not a specific app for recording financial data?

Comment: thanks for the help guys. in answer to your question, i guess i want to use python just so that i get better at using it, not because i see it as the best tool as it probably isn't!